# How to fix the error of "HTTP request failed" while calling an API in a oracle procedure?

Tags: oracle, http, plsql

I am trying to call an API from a procedure in oracle , for a demo purpose I tried calling a web page but its giving me error :
***Cause:    The UTL_HTTP package failed to execute the HTTP request.**

```
Set serveroutput on ;
DECLARE
 req   UTL_HTTP.REQ;
 resp  UTL_HTTP.RESP;
 value VARCHAR2(1024);
BEGIN
  req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST('http://www.nyquest.com');
  resp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(req);
  LOOP
    UTL_HTTP.READ_LINE(resp, value, TRUE);
    dbms_output.put_line(value);
  END LOOP;
  UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN UTL_HTTP.END_OF_BODY THEN
    UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp);
END;
```

Please guide me in fixing this error .

Comment: What's the version of your DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you didnt created ACL's.
Your database needs it before it is going to accept connections from outside.

You can read about it here:
[Oracle Access Control List](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_networkacl_adm.htm)

Comment: I am getting error identifier 'DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN' must be declared .

Comment: @radha: What version of DB do you have ?

Comment: I am using Oracle 19C

Comment: @radha probably you dont have priviliges if you didnt misspell something.
Ask your DBA to grant you an access to `DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN`.
This access should be given to you directly, not thru role.
If you are admin of the DB, simply login on `sys` user and grant priviliges to the user from which you are trying to execute the DBMS package.